# Must two permutations in $S_n$ that only differ at two adjacent positions have different signs (i.e., one is even and one is odd)?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups, permutation-cycles

**The Problem**: Must two permutations in $S_n$ that only differ at two adjacent positions have different signs (i.e., one is even and one is odd)?

For example, suppose $\sigma, \tau\in S_n$ such that $\sigma(x)=\tau(x) \forall x\in[n]-\{i, i+1\}$, $\sigma(i)=\tau(i+1)=a$ and $\sigma(i+1)=\tau(i)=b$. Then is it true that $\sigma$ and $\tau$ must have different signs (i.e., one is even and the other is odd)?

**Context**: This problem arose when I was trying to verify the proof that a determinant function on $R$ given by $det(\alpha_{ij})=\sum_{\sigma\in S_n}\epsilon(\sigma)\alpha_{\sigma(1)1}\dots\alpha_{\sigma(n)n}$ is indeed a $n$-multilinear alternating form.

**My Attempt**: I have tried a few different cases, and the statement seems to be true (which is what I wish to see); but to show it rigorously proves to be trickier. I am currently trying to make use of $\tau=\sigma\sigma^{-1}\tau$.

Comment: Try to compute $\sigma^{-1}\tau$.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: @Shaun I must confess I was indeed trying to get a quick answer...

Comment: It happens, don't worry. The temptation is there and to succumb is all too easy. Just don't make a habit of it.

Comment: @Shaun Well-said-it's the journey, not the destination, that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [sign of a permutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_of_a_permutation) is given by

$$\operatorname{sgn}(\sigma)=(-1)^{N(\sigma)}$$

where $N(\sigma)$ is the number of [inversions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_(discrete_mathematics)).

As the transposition consists of *adjacent* elements, the number of inversions changes by *exactly* one, hence the sign changes parity.

Answer (score 1):

Note $\sigma^{-1}\tau(x)=x \forall x\in[n]-\{i, i+1\}$, $\sigma^{-1}\tau(i)=i+1$, $\sigma^{-1}\tau(i+1)=i$. Thus $\sigma^{-1}\tau$ is the transposition $(i\ i+1)$. Thus $\tau=\sigma(i\ i+1)$.

Comment: Note: The two numbers need not be adjacent.

Comment: @Shaun Oh my...